# Creating method: NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am very new to C# so please bear with me.

This is my existing block of code.

```
public static class DummyClassName
{
    public static T DummyTemplateFunc1<T>(DummyInterfaceName aaa1, Func<T> action1)
    {
         T DummyVal1 = action1();
         {
             string strVal = aaa1.SomethingInInterface();
             // similar code
         }
        return DummyVal1;
    }

    public static T DummyTemplateFunc2<T>(DummyInterfaceName aaa1, Func<T> action2)
    {
        T DummyVal2 = action2();
        {
            string strVal = aaa1.SomethingInInterface();
            // similar code
        }
        return DummyVal2;
    }
}
```

My task is to avoid repetition of code and make another method to handle the repetitive code. This is what I tried.

```
public static class DummyClassName
{
    public static void DummyMethodName(DummyInterfaceName aaa1)
    {
        string strVal = aaa1.SomethingInInterface();
        // similar code
    }

    public static T DummyTemplateFunc1<T>(DummyInterfaceName aaa1, Func<T> action1)
    {
        T DummyVal1 = action1();
        DummyMethodName(aaa1);
        return DummyVal1;
    }

    public static T DummyTemplateFunc2<T>(DummyInterfaceName aaa1, Func<T> action2)
    {
        T DummyVal2 = action2();
        DummyMethodName(aaa1);
        return DummyVal1;
    }

}
```

But this is giving me a

```
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

error upon testing.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: On which line exactly? Use debugger.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what is null.

Comment: Check parameter before you use it, and if null throw an exception.

Comment: How do you call your methods?

Comment: @SonerGönül The error message points to the T DummyVal1 = action1(); line. Does that help?

Comment: Look at how you're using DummyTemplateFunctX<T>. You're not initializing something in the user code.

Comment: Your comment indicates that `action1` is null.  Check the code that calls `DummyTemplateFunc1`, that is likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T DummyTemplateFunc2<T>(DummyInterfaceName aaa1, Func<T> action2)
{
    T DummyVal1 = action1();
    DummyMethodName(aaa1);
    return DummyVal1;
}
```

The line that uses `action1` should use `action2`, right? `action1` is throwing a nullpointer reference because it doesn't know where to look for it, since it's not in the scope of your method.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake while typing my question. My aim is this: Do you see the //similar code that is repeated twice in Code block 1? I need to create a separate method for that and call that method inside the two existing templates. Does that make it clear?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but show us the code you want to generalize. This doesn't really help much. All we can say now is "extract it to a method" which is as generic as your explanation.. :)

Comment: Can you tell me if the way I have constructed the method DummyMethodName in Code Block 2 is correct or not? Forget about the error I'm getting.

Comment: I suppose..? Edit your question, state what you want. State what is not working..